# Volcar archivo .sql a Postgres heroku

Tags: sql, laravel-5, postgresql, heroku

Estoy implementando un proyecto larvel, este ya tiene una base de datos poblada. Ahora necesito desplegar este proyecto en Heroku pero no logro hacer la migración a de mi archivo .sql a postgres Heroku. he intentado con la documentación pero la sola instalación da errores y no logro seguir.
¿me podrían ayudar guiándome cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Este es uno de los errores:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar ese problema he seguido los siguientes pasos:

descargar la librería postgresql:

> https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

luego ejecutar reemplazando "x.y" por sus valores de instalación:

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/bin gem install pg
```

también puede usar:

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/x.y/bin bundle install
```

y es todo, se puede continuar con la documentación heroku

Fuente:

> https://wikimatze.de/installing-postgresql-gem-under-ubuntu-and-mac/